# To extract certain location cell values from mutiple worksheets in Excel along with worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have encountered a problem during my work.

There are over one hundred worksheets in my excel, and I would like to extract values from certain location (I25:K25, I50:K50, I95:K95) along with the worksheet name on the beside for every worksheet.

I would like to have these extracted values pasted on a new worksheet.

Does anyone know if there is any excel formula or excel macro I could use to achieve the goal?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with VBA. Loop through all worksheets (by index number), read the ranges data and write it to  a new sheet. This is a common task and you should find some tutorial how to loop through sheets and read/write data. • Give it a try your own and come back if you have some code written and got stuck or errors (because this is no free code writing service).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient with formulas, but it would certainly be doable with VBA.

Look into `For Each..Next` loops, which I think you should use to go through all sheets.

Next, the `.Name` property will extract the sheet's name for you. You can save this to a variable and fill a cell with.

Getting values from one cell to another is as easy as

```
.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B1").Value = .Sheets(2).Range("A1:B1").Value
```

Note that SO is not a free code writing service, so I won't go as far as writing the entire procedure for you. If you have some code but encounter problems, come back to us.

Useful links:

[looping through sheets](https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-loop-through-worksheets-in-a-workbook-in-excel-vba/)

[Copying cell values](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/)

[Workbook and -sheet objects](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code loop all sheets except sheet called Results, code sheet  name in column A and range values in columns B:D.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook

        Set wsResults = .Worksheets("Results")

        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Results" Then
                Lastrow = wsResults.Cells(wsResults.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                wsResults.Range("A" & Lastrow + 1 & ":A" & Lastrow + 3).Value = ws.Name
                ws.Range("I25:K25").Copy wsResults.Range("B" & Lastrow + 1)
                ws.Range("I50:K50").Copy wsResults.Range("B" & Lastrow + 2)
                ws.Range("I95:K95").Copy wsResults.Range("B" & Lastrow + 3)
            End If
        Next ws

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a minor improvement which I think is a good idea, is not to repeat a worksheets name as hardcoded string. `If ws.Name <> wsResults.Name Then` If the name changes you don't have to fix the whole procedure. Just mentioning because this drove me nuts once :)

Answer (score 0):

## Ranges to New Master Worksheet

- [Workbook
  Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8z4fmgt4mph09b/to-extract-certain-location-cell-values-from-mutiple-worksheets-in-excel-along-w_55295483.xlsm?dl=0)
  (Dropbox)
- Adjust the values in the constants (`Const`) section to fit your
  needs.
- The code will only affect the workbook containing it.
- The code will delete a possible existing worksheet named after
  `cTarget`, but will only read from all other worksheets. Then it will
  create a worksheet named after `cTarget` and write the read data to it.
- To run the code, go to the `Developer` tab and click `Macros` and
  click `RangesToNewMasterWorksheet`.

```vb
Sub RangesToNewMasterWorksheet()

    ' List of Source Row Range Addresses
    Const cRowRanges As String = "I25:K25, I50:K50, I95:K95"
    Const cTarget As String = "Result"  ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cHead1 As String = "ID"       ' 1st Column Header
    Const cHead2 As String = "Name"     ' 2nd Column Header
    Const cHead As Long = 2             ' Number of First Header Columns
    Const cRange As String = "Rng"      ' Range (Area) String
    Const cColumn As String = "C"       ' Column String
    Const cFirstCell As String = "A1"   ' Target First Cell Range Address

    Dim wb As Workbook    ' Source/Target Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet   ' Current Source/Target Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range      ' Current Source/Target Range
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim vntA As Variant   ' Areas Array
    Dim vntR As Variant   ' Range Array
    Dim NoA As Long       ' Number of Areas
    Dim NocA As Long      ' Number of Area Columns (in Target Array)

    Dim i As Long   ' Area Counter
    Dim j As Long   ' Area Column Counter
    Dim k As Long   ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim m As Long   ' Target Array Column Counter

    ' Speed Up.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ' Create a reference to ThisWorkbook i.e. the workbook containing this code.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Task: Delete a possibly existing instance of Target Worksheet.

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next
            wb.Worksheets(cTarget).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Handle unexpected error.
    On Error GoTo UnExpected

    ' Task: Calculate size of Target Array.

    ' Create a reference to the 1st worksheet. (Note: Not sheet.)
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Exit For
    Next
    ' Create a reference to the Source Row Range (in 1st worksheet.
    Set rng = ws.Range(cRowRanges)
    With rng
        NoA = .Areas.Count
        ReDim vntA(1 To NoA)
        ' Calculate Number of Area Columns (NocA).
        For i = 1 To NoA
            With .Areas(i)
                ' Write number of columns of current Area (i) to Areas Array.
                vntA(i) = .Columns.Count
                NocA = NocA + vntA(i)
            End With
        Next
    End With

    ' Resize Target Array.
    '   Rows:     Number of worksheets + 1 for headers.
    '   Columns:  Number of First Header Columns + Number of Area Columns.
    ReDim vntT(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count + 1, 1 To cHead + NocA)

    ' Task: Write 'Head' (headers) to Target Array.

    vntT(1, 1) = cHead1
    vntT(1, 2) = cHead2
    k = cHead
    For i = 1 To NoA
        For j = 1 To vntA(i)
            k = k + 1
            vntT(1, k) = cRange & i & cColumn & j
        Next
    Next

    ' Task Write 'Body' (all except headers) to Target Array.

    k = 1
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        k = k + 1
        vntT(k, 1) = k - 1
        vntT(k, 2) = ws.Name
        Set rng = ws.Range(cRowRanges)
        m = cHead
        For i = 1 To NoA
            vntR = rng.Areas(i)
            For j = 1 To vntA(i)
                m = m + 1
                vntT(k, m) = vntR(1, j)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ' Task: Copy Target Array to Target Worksheet.

    ' Add new worksheet to first tab (1).
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=wb.Sheets(1))
    ws.Name = cTarget
    ' Calculate Target Range i.e. resize First Cell Range by size of
    ' Target Array.
    Set rng = ws.Range(cFirstCell).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2))
    rng = vntT

    ' Task: Apply Formatting.

    ' Apply formatting to Target Range.
    With rng
        .Columns.AutoFit
        ' Apply formatting to Head (first row).
        With .Resize(1)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 49
            With .Font
                .ColorIndex = 2
                .Bold = True
            End With
            .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin
            .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        ' Apply formatting to Body (all except the first row).
        With .Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            With .Font
                .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                .Bold = False
            End With
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox "The program finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

ProcedureExit:

    ' Speed Down.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

Exit Sub

UnExpected:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred. Error '" & Err.Number & "': " _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo ProcedureExit

End Sub
```